# Detect alteration of AngularFireCollection with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Basically, I'm trying to use $watch with an angularFireCollection. It doesn't appear to be working however the way I want it to.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
$scope.bits = angularFireCollection(new Firebase(url).limit(75));

$scope.$watch('bits', function() {

    console.log('new');

});
```

So, when I load the page it logs "new" in the console when the data is first loaded, and that's fine, but when new data comes in, it doesn't log anything. Any idea as to why this happens?

Comment: Have you tried watching `bits.length` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$watch only looks at the object references (it compares them using ===), so since $scope.bits is always the same array instance, even though its contents have changed, it doesn't fire your listener.

You can pass an additional parameter to $watch that makes it do comparison of the contents of the objects:

```
$scope.$watch('bits', function() {}, true);
```

I'd never heard of using `bits.length` as @robertklep suggested, but that also looks elegant and I'd upvote it if he posted it as an answer.

Comment: And passing that additional parameter is much more cpu-intensive (depending on the object), right?

Comment: @bennlich it has to be a substantial nest of data to slow things down, but yeah, there's a reason it's not on by default!